# Do I need to install .Net 4.7 if I have .Net 4.8

Tags: c#, .net, windows

currently I have an application that targets .Net 4.7.0.

Is it sufficent if I install a .Net framework 4.8 on the production machine or do I have to pre install .net 4.7?

As I understand all .Net 4 frameworks are downwards compatible to the clr 4.

Is this right?

Comment: Your application will run fine. In any case, 4.x versions are binary replacements which means installing a newer one replaces the existing 4.x runtime.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos if they are replacements then why can i still select all the 4.x versions in my project?

Comment: Visual studio shows the *SDKs* installed on your machine, not the runtimes on the clients' computers.